# Checking a radio button in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I need to programmatically check a radio button given its value.  The form has an `id` and the input type obviously has a name (but no id).  The only code I managed to get working so far is:

```
$('input[name=my_name]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

But I'd like to be able to check it by explicitly providing the value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you want to select the radio which has a particular value:

```
$('input[name=my_name][value=123]').attr('checked', true); // or 'checked'
```

Answer (score 7):

Below code worked with me, if I am assigning an ID to the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="rd_male" name="gender" value="Male" />
<input type="radio" id="rd_female" name="gender" value="Female" />
```

```
$('#rd_male').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use prop instead of using attr . It's more recommended

```
    $('input[name=my_name][value=123]').prop("checked",true)
```

Comment: Not if you're using a pre 1.6 version

Answer (score 1):

In order to select the radio button programmatically, you can call a jQuery trigger or 
`$(".radioparentclass [value=radiovalue]")[0].click();`

Comment: Careful with this solution. I was using this to match up two radio selections (one was for desktop and one was for mobile) that I already had a click handler on. Triggering a click caused an infinite loop on click events. Using `.prop()` fixed this for me. Otherwise, this is the easiest solution in my mind,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=field]:eq(1)').click();
```

Note : field = radio button name property

Answer (score 0):

Recommend use .click()

The other solution that only change radio option property or attribute

will NOT trigger radio event, you have to manually call radio event.

```
  $("#your_radio_option_ID_here").click()
```